# ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Database_PDO' not found

Tags: kohana

I'm trying to extend Kohana_Database_PDO located in 
kohana\modules\database\classes\Kohana\Database

To do this I made a file in PDO.php file in 
kohana\application\classes\database

The code I am using is

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');
/**
 * PDO database connection.
 *
 * @package    Application
 * @category   Drivers
 */
class Application_Database_PDO extends Kohana_Database_PDO {} // End Database_PDO
```

I get the error:

---

**ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Database_PDO' not found**
MODPATH\database\classes\Kohana\Database.php [ 78 ]

```
// Set the driver class name
    $driver = 'Database_'.ucfirst($config['type']);
    // Create the database connection instance
    $driver = new $driver($name, $config); <- highlighted line

    // Store the database instance
    Database::$instances[$name] = $driver;
}
```

1. {PHP internal call} » Kohana_Core::shutdown_handler()

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What Kohana version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');
/**
 * PDO database connection.
 *
 * @package    Application
 * @category   Drivers
 */
class Application_Database_PDO extends Kohana_Database_PDO {} // End Database_PDO
```

is the code in your PDO.php file which resides in APPPATH/classes/Database then it is no wonder that it doesn't work.

your file should look like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
/**
 * PDO database connection.
 *
 * @package    Application
 * @category   Drivers
 */
class Database_PDO extends Kohana_Database_PDO {...
```

otherwise if you need it to be Application_... then you have to do your folderstructure like this: `APPPATH/classes/Application/Database/PDO.php`

Kohana by default explodes the Classname using the `_` as the needle and uses every string part as a directory except for the last one which is the filename

Comment: Thanks. I now have a better understanding of Kohana and the error is gone :).

Comment: I went through the same untill i had my PDO class running.